# Skeleton Framework Media queries - what do they mean?

Tags: css

I am learning how to use the basic [Skeleton Framework](http://getskeleton.com/) for responsive web design and they have the following media queries:

```
/* Mobile first queries */

/* Larger than mobile */
@media (min-width: 400px) {}

/* Larger than phablet */
@media (min-width: 550px) {}

/* Larger than tablet */
@media (min-width: 750px) {}

/* Larger than desktop */
@media (min-width: 1000px) {}

/* Larger than Desktop HD */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

Other media queries that I have seen use the `max-width` declaration but skeleton's seem to be the opposite.

I do not understand why `min-width` is used instead of `max-width`.

Any explanation would help me get my head around `min-width` instead of `max-width`.

Comment: The `min-width` is referring to a viewport (computer screen / mobile sceen) which is at least that wide. `@media (min-width: 400px) {/* Styles go here*/}` would target mobile phones. This is a mobile-first approach, where you design for mobile devices and move up to desktop views from there. Here's a good article to get your started: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Answer (score 0):

By using `min-width`, whatever CSS you write outside of the media queries will be the 'base' and will be applied to everything that is up to 400px wide; essentially making your mobile styles, which are usually the simplest styles, the 'base' styles.

This way, you are adding specific CSS on top of that, going up in width.

The alternative approach, with the `max-width` makes your desktop styles, which are usually more complex, the default styles, and then you have to "remove complexity" from the desktop styles the smaller the screen gets.

Think of it like this:

With `min-width` you build your styles incrementally, from the simplest mobile styles, until you reach your desktop size, more complex, styles

With `max-width` you "decompose" your styles incrementally,from the complex desktop styles, until you reach the simple mobile styles.